# Adding attributes to instancemethods in Python

Tags: python, instance-method

I bumped into this behaviour when trying to get class-decorators and method-decorators to play nicely together. Essentially, the method decorators would flag some of the methods as special with some dummy value, and the class decorator would come by after and fill in the value later. This is a simplified example

```
>>> class cow:
>>>     def moo(self):
>>>         print 'mooo'
>>>     moo.thing = 10
>>>
>>> cow.moo.thing
10
>>> cow().moo.thing
10
>>> cow.moo.thing = 5
AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'thing'
>>> cow().moo.thing = 5
AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'thing'
>>> cow.moo.__func__.thing = 5
>>> cow.moo.thing 
5
```

Does anyone know why `cow.moo.thing = 5` does not work, even though `cow.moo.thing` quite clearly gives me 10? And why `cow.moo.__func__.thing = 5` works? I have no idea why it does, but in randomly fiddling with stuff in the `dir(cow.moo)` list trying to get something to work it suddenly did, and i have no idea why.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For attribute lookup, Python is automatically using the real function attached to the instance method for you.

For attribute setting, it is not.

They are two separate operations depending on which side of the statement you're on, even though they both use the `.` operator.

When you access an instance method's `__func__`, you're manually accessing the real function that actually has the `moo` attribute.

In Python 3 this will work as you would like / expect as methods are basically just functions.

Comment: Sorry for reviving an old post but in Python3 `cow().moo.thing = 5` is returning `AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'thing'`. Do you know why ?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin On the instance (`cow().moo`) the function is wrapped in a method object in any version of Python  -- the difference is on the class (`cow.moo`) it's not wrapped in Python 3. The wrapping is necessary for `self` to get passed automatically to the function.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why I was having trouble adding attributes to an instance method on the fly.

Comment: How do you set the attribute to an instance method then?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to modify the function attributes of both functions and instance methods from C then you have to check the type of callable you have.

So assuming you have a PyObject of some type of callable you can check it like this:

```
PyObject *callable;  // set to something callable
PyObject *setting;  // set to something
if(PyMethod_Check(callable)){
    PyObject_SetAttrString(PyMethod_Function(callable),"attribute",setting);
}else{
    PyObject_SetAttrString(callable,"attribute",setting);
}
...
// and the inverse
if(PyMethod_Check(callable){         
     if(PyObject_HasAttrString(PyMethod_Function(callable),"attribute")){
        PyObject_DelAttrString(PyMethod_Function(callable),"attribute");
     }
  }else{
     if(PyObject_HasAttrString(callable,"attribute")){
        PyObject_DelAttrString(callable,"attribute");
     }
  }
```

Now the code agf pointed out works from within Python for instance methods.  If I just try to set the attribute of the instance method it would not find the attribute no matter how I tried to access it from Python.

I ran into this issue and Li Haoyi's question with agf's answer helped me understand what needed to be changed.  I figured someone will find this question and answer again while looking for how to solve this issue through C.

**Edit:**
Note: This is for Python 2.7.x.  Python 3.x uses different function calls.