# class attribute default value doesn't receive the mock

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

I'm unit testing a module I wrote and encountering a problem with default class object provided to a function that has a mock for it.
This is how it looks in high level:

main_file.py

```
class MainClass(object):
    def main_func(self):
        sub_class_obj = SubClass()
        sub_class_obj.sub_func()
```

sub_file.py

```
class SubClass(object):
    def sub_func(self, my_att=Helper(2)):
        self.my_att = my_att
```

helpers.py

```
class Helper():
    def __init__(self, my_val):
        self.my_val = my_val
```

test.py

```
class TestClass(object):
    @patch('sub_file.Helper', MockHelper)
    def my_test(self):
        main_class_obj = MainClass()
        main_class_obj.main_func()
```

When I do that in a way that my_att is provided - all works well and the Mock is called, but when I don't and the default value is set - I get the original Helper class object.

Any idea how to make the default value for this attribute to receive the mock as well?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the default value is read at import time, so it is already set in the function before you patch `Helper`. The defaults are saved in the function object at that point.

You can, however, also patch the default arguments of your function (which can be accessed via `__defaults__`:

```py
from sub_file import SubClass

class TestClass(object):
    @patch('sub_file.Helper', MockHelper)
    @patch.object(SubClass.sub_func, "__defaults__", (MockHelper(),))
    def my_test(self):
        main_class_obj = MainClass()
        main_class_obj.main_func()
```

Note that `__defaults__` has to be a tuple of arguments.

You could also use `monkeypatch` to do the same:

```py
from sub_file import SubClass

class TestClass(object):
    @patch('sub_file.Helper', MockHelper)
    def my_test(self, monkeypatch):
        monkeypatch.setattr(SubClass.sub_func, "__defaults__", (MockHelper(),)     
        main_class_obj = MainClass()
        main_class_obj.main_func()
```

*UPDATE*:
I didn't realize that this would not work with Python 2. Apart from the other name of the default arguments (`func_defaults` instead of `__defaults__`) this would only work with standalone functions, but not with methods, as `setattr` [is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034063/adding-attributes-to-instancemethods-in-python) in this case in Python 2. Here is a workaround for Python 2:

```py
from sub_file import SubClass

class TestClass(object):
    @patch('sub_file.Helper', MockHelper)
    def my_test(self):
        orig_sub_func = SubClass.sub_func
        with patch.object(SubClass, "sub_func",
                          lambda o, attr=MockHelper(): orig_sub_func(o, attr)):
            main_class_obj = MainClass()
            main_class_obj.main_func()
```

This way, the original `sub_func` is replaced by a function that has its own default value, but otherwise delegates the functionality to the original function.

*UPDATE 2*:
Just saw the answer by @chepner, and it is correct: the best way would be to refactor your code accordingly. Only if you cannot do this, you try this answer.

Comment: And what if the sub class is the __init__? It doesn't seem to work... I tried:
```
@patch.object(SubClass.__init__, "func_defaults", (MockHelper(),))
```
and got this error - AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'func_defaults' (I'm working with Python 2.7, hence the func_defaults instead of __defaults__...)

Comment: I had overlooked that this was in Python 2, sorry. I added an update for Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Default values are created when the function is *defined*, not when it is called. It's too late to patch `Helper` in your test, because `SubClass.__init__` has already been defined.

Rather than patching anything, though, re-write `MainClass` so that there is no hard-coded reference to `SubClass`: then you can create the proper instance yourself without relying on a default value.

You can pass an instance directly:

```
class MainClass(object):
    def main_func(self, sub_class_obj):
        sub_class_obj.sub_func()

class TestClass(object):
    def my_test(self):
        mock_obj = MockHelper()
        main_class_obj = MainClass(mock_obj)
        main_class_obj.main_func()
```

or take a factory function that will be called to create the subclass object.

```
class MainClass(object):
    def main_func(self, factory=SubClass):
        sub_class_obj = factory()
        sub_class_obj.sub_func()

class TestClass(object):
    def my_test(self):
        main_class_obj = MainClass(lambda: SubClass(MockHelper()))
        main_class_obj.main_func()
```